# Angular app is not building anymore. build-long.md was not found

Tags: angular, angular-cli

After making a minor update to the @angular-devkit/build-angular package, the build script is not working anymore. When I start the build with `ng build app --base-href /app/ --output-path ./dist/app/de/ --deployUrl /en/app/ --configuration=dev` an unhandled exception occurs:

`An unhandled exception occurred: File C:\Users\<User>\Projects\<project>\angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\build-long.md was not found while constructing the subcommand build.`

After that I upgraded to the newest version 9 and re-installed the complete package with the same result. I also updated `@angular/cli` and `@angular/compiler-cli` which changed nothing. I removed the `node_modules` folder and re-installed everything. The problem persists...

Then I downgraded `@angular-devkit/build-angular` to version `0.802.2.` (which was lower than the version we used before the upgrade) and exact the same problem.

I looked into the package and there is no `build-long.md` file. Why is this problem occuring? Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading anular using the official way? `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`?

Comment: Try doing a fresh installation of the packages after you reverted `@angular-devkit/build-angular`.  I use `"installclean": "find . -name \"node_modules\" -exec rm -rf '{}' + && npm install"` in my `package.json`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found the problem. Yarn creates a `.yarnclean` file when cleaning the `node_modules` and there it excludes `.md` files from the installed packages.

So I had to remove the `.md` entry from the `yarnclean` file and install all packages again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just Deleting my node_modules folder and running npm i again worked for me.